# Upgrade mysql2 gem to latest version with rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, docker-compose, dockerfile, mysql2

i have tried to update mysql2 gem but error are there:

```
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

i have to upgrade mysql2 gem to latest version because i have to do data migration from mysql to postgresql that why we need to upgrade mysql2 gem.
also i need to dump data of mysql database that why i need to upgrade mysql2 gem to latest version.
if any one have suggestion how to done this work so, please help me and mail to: santu.essence@gmail.com

docker file:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.2
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN apt-get update -y --force-yes
RUN apt-get install libtag1-dev -y --force-yes
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install nodejs -y 
# postgresql-client --- postgresql database adapter
# RUN apt-get install -y wget sudo pgloader
# install ffmpeg
# RUN apt-get install checkinstall
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y git build-essential gcc make yasm autoconf automake cmake libtool libmp3lame-dev pkg-config libunwind-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get clean
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libc6-dev libgdiplus wget software-properties-common \
    && wget https://www.ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-4.0.2.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzf ffmpeg-4.0.2.tar.gz; rm -r ffmpeg-4.0.2.tar.gz \
    && cd ./ffmpeg-4.0.2; ./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-decoder=mjpeg,png --enable-encoder=png --enable-openssl --enable-nonfree \
    && cd ./ffmpeg-4.0.2; make \
    && cd ./ffmpeg-4.0.2; make install \
    # ffmpeg installation complete
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# RUN mkdir -p .bundle && printf '%s\n%s\n' '---' 'BUNDLE_WITHOUT: development:test' > .bundle/config
COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN gem install bundler -v 2.2.28
RUN bundle install
COPY . .
# ENTRYPOINT ./entrypoint-web.sh
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6.45
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: youspin_development
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

# volumes:
#   ./tmp/db:
#     external: true

  worker:
    # set the path for Dockerfile
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f /usr/src/app/tmp/pids/resque.pid && rake app:worker-start "
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/0
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  web:
    # set the path for Dockerfile
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f /usr/src/app/tmp/pids/server.pid && rake assets:clobber app:init app:serve && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/0
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
      - worker
      - redis

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx.dev.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./public:/var/www/youspin/public
    ports:
      - 80:80
    environment:
      - NGINX_PORT=80
    links:
      - web
```

Comment: I see you use docker. Please update the `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile`. How are you loading the gems? Through a volume?

Comment: `docker compose build` should help if you do `bundle install` in `Dockerfile`. If you use volumes `docker compose run --rm --no-deps app bundle install` should also work.

Comment: i am loading gems through docker file

Comment: Do you have a bundle install there? Update with the files I requested above please.

Comment: i can do bundle install using dockerfile

Comment: no i can not do bundle install without dockerfile

Comment: Of course you can't. bundle install is performed inside the container. Try `docker compose build --no-cache` then `docker compose run`

Comment: can you give how to use mysql 8.0 image with dockerfile

Comment: This question is about gems, your container does not see the mysql gem. What I've been writing above is to help you fix that. I asked 2 times for the compose yml and dockerfile and you did not provide anything.

Comment: now i have provided both file you can see above.

Comment: If you want mysql 8 change in docker-compose.yml `mysql:latest` or `mysql:8.0`. For the bundle, try `docker compose build --no-cache` then `docker compose run`. Update the description with any error you get.